# I upgrade atom but its version does not change

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I am a ubuntu-16.04 user and want to upgrade atom to use teletype package.

What I do is:

1. go to atom's releases page( github.com/atom/atom/releases )
2. install the latest version which is 1.24.0-beta1 (atom-amd64.deb)
3. `sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb` on terminal. It says *Unpacking atom-beta (1.24.0-beta1) over (1.23.0-beta1)*

When I check atom's version with `atom -v` I get:

```
Atom : 1.20.1 Electron: 1.6.9 Chrome : 56.0.2924.87 Node : 7.4.0
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have atom installed elsewhere on the system. 1.24beta was installed replacing 1.23beta, but the atom version shows a lower version, so there's probably an installation somewhere else that's picked up first before the one installed by dpkg (higher up in $PATH than the system directories)

Comment: I found out that atom-beta does not override atom. They are installed separately so I installed teletype package in atom-beta.